# How do I make my Safari browser extension have read access to all sites immediately after installation?

Tags: browser-extension, safari-web-extension

For example, Grammarly has the following permissions after installation.
[image: Grammarly extension permissions]

So it works on every website and don't ask for access.
In my case I have the following permissions:
[image: Safari extension permissions]

And I need to go to the settings and allow it separately.

[image]

What can I do?